# Creating an array that stores strings and integers in java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I would like to create an array that stores the names (String) and values (integer) of company stocks, but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Any tries by yourself?

Comment: Create a class to hold these attributes and then create an array to hold instances of this class.

Comment: If the name is the key then use an map like Map<String,int> myMap = HashMap<String,int>(); Or if you realy need an array you can use an object which holds the variables.

Comment: Or use a Map<String, Integer>

Comment: You have a typo: interger is supposed to be integer. Please fix it

Comment: @Billy you mis-spelled **integer** (it's not called inte**r**ger). Why did you roll-back the fix to your spelling error?

Comment: @Erwin. it was an oversight on my part. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 2):

An `Object[]` can hold both `String` and `Integer` objects.  Here's a simple example:

```
    Object[] mixed = new Object[2];
    mixed[0] = "Hi Mum";
    mixed[1] = Integer.valueOf(42);
    ...
    String message = (String) mixed[0];
    Integer answer = (Integer) mixed[1];
```

However, if you put use an `Object[]` like this, you will typically need to use `instanceof` and / or type casts when accessing the elements.

Any design that routinely involves `instanceof` and/or type casts needs to be treated with suspicion.  In most cases, there is a better (more object-oriented, more efficient, less fragile) way of achieving the same ends.

In your particular use-case, it sounds like what you really need is a mapping object that maps from `String` (names) to `Integer` (numbers of stocks).  And the nice thing about Java is that there are existing library classes that provide this functionality; e.g. the `HashMap<K,V>` class, with `String` as the key type and `Integer` as the value type.

Another possibility might be an array, `List` or `Set` of some custom or generic pair class.  These have different semantic properties to `Map` types.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

1. Use an array.

> ```
> public class Value {
>   public String name;
>   public int number;
> }
>
> ...
> public Value[] values = new Value[10];
> ....
> ```

2. Use a map which has much more comfort, specially you can use the name as key to get a value

> ```
> ....
> public Map<String, int> valueMap = new HashMap<String,int>();
> valueMap.put("Sample",10);
> int value = valueMap.get("Sample");
> ...
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Map data structure instead of an array. This is basically a type of Collection that has key-value pairs. Your string name can be used as the key and the value is your integer.

```
Map<String,Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>;

MyMap.put("someone", 6);
```

Note that using a HashMap has a speed advantage over an array during lookup. The complexity of HashMap lookup is O(log(n)) while that of an array is O(n).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The question i have specifically asks for an array.