# Generically apply solution to get values from object array holding both String and Integer

Tags: java, java-8

I'm extending the question further here - [Creating an array that stores strings and integers in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402861/creating-an-array-that-stores-strings-and-integers-in-java).

I'm looking to generically implement below solution.

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] values = {"Cat", 4, "Bat", 2};
        
        // expected result should be => Bat, 2, Cat, 4 - Any pointers?
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "output" ?  Is this the visible result of some sort of print statement?   Then cycle through the array and print the result of calling toString on each element.

Comment: Yes its a print statement. Can you suggest solution or pointer?

Comment: Or do you want to somehow consider the array as holding 'key1, val1, key2, val2'.  And print in lexical order of keys?  The first thing to say is that this is a totally inappropriate data structure for the use. Use some sort of sorted map.

Comment: Is there a relation between String and int. If so, you can use Map<String, Integer>. Or you can use stream and map operator to transform each element to string after that you can use reduce to generate the string

Comment: If you've already *got* an array, then use it to load a (temporary) TreeMap, and then cycle through the map in order.

Comment: Can anyone please show some code ? Its expected to get result like this.  Bat, 2, Cat, 4, Dat, 6 like this. But this problem statement I got. Please guide

Comment: Why should the result be that? What makes "Bat, Dat, Cat, 2, 4, 6" the wrong result?

Comment: Like i said you can use Arrays.stream to produce the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the task is about sorting the pairs of elements of the input array (however, all elements are `Comparable`) and it can be resolved without creating/using `Pair` class with the help of Stream API.

Also, the output result is also an array of objects.

```java
Object[] values = { "Cat", 4, "Bat", 4, "Dat", 6, "Bat", 2 };

// prepare comparators
Comparator<List<Comparable>> comparator0 = Comparator.comparing(list -> list.get(0));
Comparator<List<Comparable>> comparator1 = Comparator.comparing(list -> list.get(1));

Object[] sorted = IntStream.range(0, values.length / 2)
         .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.asList((Comparable)values[2 * i], (Comparable)values[2 * i + 1]))
         .sorted(comparator0.thenComparing(comparator1))
         .flatMap(List::stream)
         .toArray(Object[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sorted));
```

Output:

```
[Cat, 4, Bat, 4, Dat, 6, Bat, 2]
[Bat, 2, Bat, 4, Cat, 4, Dat, 6]
```

`.sorted` may use `Comparator` written in this equivalent form:

```
sorted((a1, a2) -> a1.get(0).compareTo(a2.get(0)) == 0 
        ? a1.get(1).compareTo(a2.get(1)) 
        : a1.get(0).compareTo(a2.get(0))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String,Integer> temp = new TreeMap<>();
for (int v=0; v<values.length-1; v+=2)
    temp.put((String)values[v], (Integer)values[v+1]);
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> e : temp.entrySet())
    System.out.printf(" %s : %s ", e.getKey(), e.getValue());
```

Check the method names with the doc, this is off the top of my head.

Comment: @user15187356 : Juste replace for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> e : temp)  with for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> e : temp.entrySet()) .And the code will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using a generic `Pair<T, E>` class and an `ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>` to keep with array's random access.

```
// entry point of the program
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Object[] values = { "Cat", 4, "Bat", 4, "Dat", 6, "Bat", 2 };
    
    // create the list of pairs
    List<Pair<String, Integer>> pairs = new ArrayList<>(values.length / 2);
    
    // iterate over values, construct pairs and add them to the list
    for (int i = 0, n = values.length - 1; i < n; i += 2) {
        // note that we have to cast Object to String and Integer
        pairs.add(new Pair<String, Integer>((String) values[i], (Integer) values[i + 1]));
    }
    
    // sort the list
    pairs.sort((p1, p2) -> p1.compareTo(p2));
    
    // output each pair via Pair#toString
    pairs.forEach(pair -> System.out.printf("%s, ", pair));
}
    
private static class Pair<T extends Comparable<? super T>, E extends Comparable<? super E>>
implements Comparable<Pair<T, E>>
{
    private T first;
    private E last;

    public Pair(T first, E last) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }

    public T getFirst() { return first; }
    public E getLast() { return last; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return String.format("%s, %s", first, last); }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair<T, E> what) {
        // throw an NPE if this.compareTo(null), per Comparable's Javadoc
        final Pair<T, E> that = Objects.requireNonNull(what);
        
        if (this == that) { return 0; }
        
        int cmpFirst = 0;
        
        // handle this.first being null
        if (this.first == null) {
            if (that.first != null) { return -1; }
        } else {
            if (that.first == null) { return 1; }
            
            cmpFirst = this.first.compareTo(that.first);
        }
        
        // handle this.first not equaling that.first
        if (cmpFirst != 0) { return cmpFirst; }
        
        // handle this.last being null
        if (this.last == null) {
            if (that.last != null) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        
        // at this point this.first == that.first and this.last != null
        return this.last.compareTo(that.last);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Bat, 2, Bat, 4, Cat, 4, Dat, 6,
```

Comment: You also need to check if `this.{first,last} != null && that.{first,last} == null`.

Comment: @k314159 the `compareTo(...)` methods of `Pair.first` and `Pair.last` have the responsibility of handling a `null` argument.

Comment: The javadoc for Comparable specifies that compareTo() should throw NullPointerException if the passed object is null. So I think that means you should also throw the exception if 'this.first/second' is null. Or just check org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair and do whatever it does.

Comment: @k314159 you're correct in regard to `Pair.compareTo(null)`, updated my code to throw an NPE. However, the Javadoc for `Comparable` stipulates nothing about the handling of `null` members, see [What should int compareTo() return when the parameter string is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6259354/what-should-int-compareto-return-when-the-parameter-string-is-null). Though I think I need to update my code to ensure antisymmetry, reflexivity and transitivity.